# Get specific result by checking a simple variable inside a double array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, find

I have a `@customers` variable in which each `customer` has multiple `contracts`. Each of those `contract` has multiple `users`.

What I would like to do is to get all the `customers` that have a specific `user`

I tried using the `find` method but I don't understand how to do that inside a what seems to be double array.

Currently I have this:

```
cust.each do |c|
      if c.contracts.where(users.find(session[:login]))
        @customers << c
      end
  end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to mention user field in where clause, Can you try below code

```
cust.each do |c|
      if c.contracts.where(user: users.find(session[:login]))
        @customers << c
      end
end
```

Comment: Seems to be working, however I get the following error:

`undefined method `<<'`

I'm initializing `@customers` with `Customer.new`

Would there be a way to find the `contracts` like you did with the `users`? I would avoid using a loop. Something like a double `where`.

Comment: if you are using `@customers`  to store all objects of customers so that should be an array instead of Customer class object, i guess you should used.  
`@customers =[]` 
so the push "<<" customer object will work and you will have all customers object in `@customers =[]` Array.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured out. However, the Kaminari paginate method won't work on array like these. I'm currently trying another solution. Thanks a lot for your help. I mark this topic resolved, since the main objective was to parse the results and it worked.